# how do hide NavigationBar indicatorColor?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

#### question

I am using the android material3 library and want to change the color transparency of the indicator, but the source code uses color transparency by default to control the display or hide, how should I control the display and hide of the indicator?

#### Navigation bar source code

```kotlin
  val animationProgress: Float by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = if (selected) 1f else 0f,
            animationSpec = tween(ItemAnimationDurationMillis)
        )

        val indicator = @Composable {
            Box(
                Modifier.layoutId(IndicatorLayoutIdTag)
                    .background(
                        color = colors.indicatorColor.copy(alpha = animationProgress),
                        shape = NavigationBarTokens.ActiveIndicatorShape.toShape(),
                    )
            )
        }
```

The indicator refers to the position of marker 4 on this picture：[image: navigationBar images tag]

Comment: Do you want to hide NavigationBar indicatorColor (title) or do you want to change the trasparency?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in summary, I want to hide the effect of the navbar indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the library that Google created for this kind of things. It is called **Accompanist** and can be found here: https://github.com/google/accompanist.

Also, here you have some documentation: https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/

After you add the dependency for that library

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.26.2-beta"
```

you can do something like

```
systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
    color = Color.Transparent
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer，But this is the control system ui may not be the effect I want, What I want to hide is the indicator of [this component](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs), which is the style numbered 4 in the picture above.